# Is it possible to set a delay time for iBeacon prompts to occur?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, proximity

I am new to iBeacons but I was wondering if it is possible to send users in the proximity a delayed prompt rather than an instant prompt the second they arrive in the proximity.

I am a cafe owner and I would like to send out separate prompts for users that has spent different period of times in the cafe. Thereby, if a user has stayed at my cafe for 30 minutes, I want to give users a unique prompt when the 30 minute period is up rather than it being a constant transmission of data.

Answer (score 2):

On the face of it, the answer is yes.

If you are building your own app, you can handle the proximity event and simply set a timer to trigger your notification in thirty minute's time.

In iOS, this could be achieved using Region Monitoring and a scheduled Local Notification.

Does this help?

Comment: The trouble with the scheduled Local Notification is that the user would get the notification 30 minutes after arriving regardless of whether they had already left the cafe or not.

Comment: Looking more, this could work, if you add code on `didExitRegion` in iOS to cancel the local notification.  See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelAllLocalNotifications

Comment: That's true. There could be the issue of an alert being triggered within a few minutes of leaving a region (as iBeacon region triggering isn't always instant). A possible alternative is a background app refresh that could do some active ranging of nearby beacons to determine if the notification is still valid.